# Z-transform of $\cos(\omega_0 n(n+1))u[n]$

Tags: z-transform, cosine

I'm doing some research on Zadoff-Chu sequences and as a part of it I wanted to find the Z-transform of:
$$\cos(\omega_0 n(n+1))u[n]$$
Wolfram Alpha / Mathematica couldn't help out. I couldn't find a way to do this from identities so I tried doing it from 1st principles.
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{Z}\{\cos(\omega_0 n(n+1))u[n]\} &= \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \cos(\omega_0 n(n+1)) z^{-n} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (e^{j\omega_0(n+1)}z^{-1})^n + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n = 0}^\infty(e^{-j\omega_0(n+1)}z^{-1})^n
\end{aligned}
$$

This is where I'm not sure how to proceed. If the initial expression was just $\cos(\omega_0 n)u[n]$ then it would be straight forward to use the infinite sum of the geometric series. But here the required relation is:
$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (ka^{(n+1)})^n = \;? \;\;,\;\; |a| = 1$$
I've tried researching it and the closest I've come is looking at Jacobi Theta functions:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function

Some simple MATLAB simulations show that the sequence does converge, I'm just not sure if there's a way to find a closed-form answer to it analytically.

Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: Just a guess, but since there is an $n^2$ in the argument, this is a *"chirp"* which is directly related to a gaussian which has a known Fourier transform.

Comment: Zadoff-Chu sequences are _finite length_ sequences (or periodic sequences if you prefer) and so the chirp frequency does not increase forever. The $z$-transforms are _polynomials_ in $z^{-1}$, not infinite series as you have written.